# How can code using a framework class run without the framework?

Tags: ios, frameworks, linker, external-accessory

I'm running an app that uses EAAccessoryManager, which should only be available via the ExternalAccessory framework. Yet it compiles and runs without ExternalAccessory being included in the list of frameworks to link. Nor is it loaded into Xcode by any other targets. How is this possible? I'm mystified.

I'm curious because I have another project that loads a static library that also references EAAccessoryManager, and in *that* case, the app won't compile, exiting with the error `Undefined symbols for architecture i386`. This is more what I expect. What can account for the difference?

Comment: Look up the difference between static and dynamic linking and you will find your answer.  I bet it will have problems once it gets to the section that tries to use the functionality.

Comment: Nope, the app uses the class from the EAAccessoryManager without problem, even though ExternalAccessory is not listed in frameworks to link.

Comment: That's odd behavior then.  You'll have to get an answer from someone who knows more than me.

Comment: Is the working example running on a device? Because the non-working example sounds like it is running on the simulator.

Comment: I'm running both on a simulator, @RhythmicFistman.

Comment: could you be using the new @import (automatic linking/semantic import) feature somewhere?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman Does not appear so; grep doesn’t find `@import` anywhere. Just ran it on my device, too, no problems. I do not understand how this is possible!

Comment: what does otool -L say about your binary?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman Ah ha! It is in there! But how the hell is it getting in there??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Build Settings, in the “Apple LLVM 5.1 – Languages – Modules” section, “Link Frameworks Automatically” is enabled:

[image]

This is a new feature I never noticed before discovered while reading [this post on `@import`](http://stoneofarc.wordpress.com/2013/06/25/introduction-to-objective-c-modules/) (thanks @RhythmicFistman for the hint!). When I change that setting to “No”, I get the linker errors I expect.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a linker build setting rather than a link build phase.

Comment: Oops, I meant to post this as a comment. Silly responsive web version.